# Attempting to correct the position from which the "player" follows the control(cursor)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have started a new project and decided to do the hardest part of the program first, when I say hardest I mean the niggly bits.

The code below has my player following the mouse cursor but the movement is constant and the player's position is relative to the cursor's position to the screen and not the actual program window.The closer the window it to the top corner of the screen the closer the cursor and player become.

I am looking for assistance to correct this so that the player's position moves to the cursor's at a certain speed but actually follows the pointer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace games1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void Form1_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
                Invalidate();
        }
       private void tmrMoving_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (tmrMoving.Enabled == true)
        {
            var cursPoint = new System.Drawing.Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
            var playerPoint = new System.Drawing.Point(player.Location.X, player.Location.Y);
            var diff = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - playerPoint.X, Cursor.Position.Y - playerPoint.Y);
            var speed = Math.Sqrt(diff.X * diff.X + diff.Y * diff.Y);
            if (speed > 10)
            {
                diff.X /= (int)(speed / 10);
                diff.Y /= (int)(speed / 10);
            }
            player.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(player.Location.X + diff.X, player.Location.Y + diff.Y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is the Method PointToClient().

You can call it on a control. If you call it for instance on your form, you can use it to transform the position of the cursor (which is relative to the screen) to a point relative to the form (which is the client in this case).

To explore this behaviour you can create a new empty project with an empty form and bind the MouseUp-Event of the form to this handler.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(Form1_MouseUp);
    }

    private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("X: " + Cursor.Position.X + " - Y: " + Cursor.Position.Y);
        var goodCoordinates = PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        Console.WriteLine("X: " + goodCoordinates.X + " - Y: " + goodCoordinates.Y);
    }
```

You will want to correct your code like so:

```
var cursPoint = PointToClient(new System.Drawing.Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y));
```

Comment: Yeah, sry about that. I forgot not everybody is using visual studio and its output-view for debugging. You can also put two labels on the form instead instead and change their text values accordingly...

Comment: @Toastgeraet You could also use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` ;)

Comment: Thank you icepickle. I will try to employ that technique in the future to improve the quality of my code. Obviously my method isn't very clear, but rather crude.